# C Socket TCP, send array to server and response back to client in loop

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm very new to socket and TCP, I'm trying to send an array of Int to the server, do some sorting and calculating, then send back the result to the client and repeat.

I tried a few different ways, I either got the result after I close the client or got into a infinite loop.

What is the proper way to keep reading from the client until the client hit EOF?

Here is my server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int sock, csock, readSize, addressSize;
    char buf[256];

    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(5999);

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
    listen(sock, 5);

    addressSize = sizeof(client);
    csock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &addressSize);

    int values[5];

    while (read(csock, values, sizeof(values))) {

        // Some sorting and calculating here

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("%d ", values[i]);
        }
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my client code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buf[256];
    int sock;

    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(5999);

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    while (1) {
        int values[5] = {0};

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
            scanf("%d", &values[i]);
        
        write(sock, values, sizeof(values));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"or got into a infinite loop"` -- Did the infinite loop occur in the server or client or both?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It only occur in the server.

Comment: `"I either got the result after I close the client"` -- Who is 'I"? The client or the server? If it is the client, how can the client receive the result after it has been closed? And how did you close the client? With CTRL-C?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes I closed the client with  CTRL-C. Actually I took out the response code in the server because I can't even print out the result properly in the server side.

Comment: Check errors code.

Comment: @AllanWind What errors code? I'm running on Ubuntu, I don't see any error.

Comment: All your networking calls potentially return errors.  socket, accept, read, write, bind etc.

Comment: In the server code, I suggest that you change `while (read(csock, values, sizeof(values)))` to `while ( read(csock, values, sizeof(values)) == (ssize_t)sizeof(values) )`. Also, it seems a bit dangerous to assume that you will always receive 5 bytes at once, but in this case with user input involved, it seems ok for test purposes.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I changed it, the result still only showing after I closed the client.

Comment: It is impossible to write correct networking (or indeed I/O) code without storing the result of `read()` into a variable, and then checking it for (1) -1 and acting accordingly, which means closing the socket, probably logging an error, and forgetting the connection; (2) 0 and acting accordingly, which means closing the socket and forgetting the connection; or (3) using the (positive) value accordingly, i.e. as the count of bytes received. And it is entirely fallacious to assume that and `read()` should fill the buffer supplied. @AndreasWenzel's comment is therefore no improvement whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, I observed that if client is terminated with Ctrl-C, then server exits when `read()` returns 0 to signify `EOF`.  If client is given a Ctrl-D, the stream's error state is set and this and all future scanf calls fail without setting `values`.  This means `values` retain their zero initialization, which is sent to server in each iteration of the infinite loop.

Per @user207421, `recv()` which I guess how `read()` is implemented may return on error on windows to signify and errors.  In this case, server would loop with the original code.

In either case, I added error checking for most of calsl (you should also add it for `inet_addr()`), and the server will terminate if `read()` returns either -1 or 0:

server:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int sock, csock;
    socklen_t addressSize;

    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(5999);

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1) {
        printf("socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        printf("bind: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if(listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
        printf("listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    addressSize = sizeof(client);
    csock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &addressSize);
    if(csock == -1) {
        printf("listen: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    int values[5];
    ssize_t n;
    while ((n = read(csock, values, sizeof(values)))) {
        printf("read %zd\n", n);
        if(n <= 0) break;
        for (int i = 0; i < n / sizeof(*values); i++) {
            printf("%d ", values[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

and client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buf[256];
    int sock;

    bzero(&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(5999);

    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock == -1) {
        printf("socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        printf("connect: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }


    while (1) {
        int values[5] = {0};

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int r = scanf("%d", &values[i]);
            if(r == EOF) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        ssize_t n = write(sock, values, sizeof(values));
        if(n == -1) {
            printf("write: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        printf("wrote %zd\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the output from the server:

```
$ ./server 
read 20 bytes
1 2 3 4 5
```

and the client (note; client doesn't send partial data):

```
$ ./client 
1
2
3
4
5
wrote 20
1
```

Comment: It doesn't 'mean 0 values were being sent to server (forever).' Nothing is sent at all after the client exits. The server *receives* 0 values from `recv()` forever, but not because they were sent: it is because `recv()` knows the socket is at end of stream because of the client disconnect.

Comment: In the original client code `values` is initialized to {0} in the loop, `scanf` is terminated with ctrl-d, which means this and subsequent calls to `scanf` return `EOF`, and  the initialized values are subsequently sent to the server.

Comment: @user207421 You are not wrong,  but I also made server changes to address read() failing or returning 0 on eof.  If I am still missing something let me know.

Comment: @user207421 client does NOT exit when ctrl-d is entered to scanf with original code.

Comment: I doh't know why you're telling me that. It has nothing to do with what I actually wrote, which you still haven't acted on after several edits.

Comment: In comments section, OP stated that they were using `CTRL-C` to close client, not `CTRL-D`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I was not able to reproduce that behavior of original code.  If client is terminated with ctrl-c then server terminates too.  server's `read()` would return 0 (to signify EOF) when connection is closed on client side.

Comment: @user207421 updated answer to clarify that I tested this on Linux only and what I observed.  Added a section to reflect that server would loop if `read()` returned an error (-1).   Let me know if I missing anything.

Comment: @user207421 ... and I am certain it is correct as written.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Then you are certainly, and still, wrong. Your answer now says ' If client is given a Ctrl-D, it would go into an infinite loop and sending zero values.'. It is *already* in an infinite (`while (1)`) loop, and once it has exited it can't send anything, let alone zero values. What you describe is not only incorrect but a logical impossibility. It is incredible to me that you cannot see that, even after being told several times.

Comment: @user207421 it seems pedantic to infer that "go into" means a different infinite loop than the one and only infinite loop in the code but clarified language never the less.  In any case I doubt that I will be able to satisfy what you expect out of my answer.  Please write your own answer.  I am sure it will be better than mine (no shade intended).  You keep insisting that I am wrong, yet for whatever reason fail to understand that client does *NOT* exit when sent ctrl-d with op's original code.  Have you tried running op's code on Linux?

Comment: It seems considerably less than 'pedantic' to me to assert the the word 'go' doesn't actually mean 'go', it just means 'continue'. It doesn't. As to the rest of it, *prove it.* Support your claim. Show us the evidence that the client keeps transmitting zeros after the Ctrl/d. A Wireshark packet trace for example. WIthout that your answer amounts to no more than guesswork, which you have failed to support even after numerous challenges.